# When using the simple_salesforce package in python to ingest Account, the following error is given related to collections.OrderedDict', 'HY105')

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, simple-salesforce

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this. For days I'm figuring out why I get this error when I try to load Account data towards an mssql database. The connection is fine.

But I keep on getting these errors:

`(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=17 param-type=collections.OrderedDict', 'HY105')`

`Exception: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'Id'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")`

`Exception: One or more values in the dataframe have more characters than possible in the database table. The maximum number of characters in each column are:`

How can I circumvent these errors and load the data without errors:

I use this for instance:

```
 engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params))
    conn = engine.connect()


    for entity in ['Account']:

        df = get_salesforce_data(sf=sf, sf_object=entity, method=method)
        df.to_sql(entity, con = engine, if_exists ='append', index = False, chunksize = 1000)
```

There 94 columns in this Account table?

Thank you for thinking with me

Comment: Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Based on the last chunk of the error message, it looks like one of the fields in your Salesforce data exceeds the max number of characters allowed in the database column. Have you checked that as the potential issue?